# How can i take my mysql database into Master Slave configuration for data backup and separation of inserts and selects

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I have a huge database almost 5M records and its growing at a high speed.
I have a Query for report generation which joins 4 tables and the time it takes is not pretty.
I want to replicate my database on a slave instance and separate inserts and select.
So when i select data it goes to master and on inserts goes to slave and replicates the data whenever either one is updated.
Whats your suggestion on this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, this question is very similar to [the one you posted a couple of hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981860/mysql-scalability-master-slave-replication-a-good-idea-read-description-please). Instead of posting two very similar questions, please note you can edit a question. The present question could be considered a duplicate of the other one, and therefore is likely to be closed, and you might be flagged for multi-posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL terminology, user insertions and updates are directed to the Master, such changes are then forwarded to the Slave (so it is the other way around).

If you want a bi-directional synchronisation, you will need to consider circular replication ([here](http://www.onlamp.com/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html) is a good tutorial).

The next step is [clustering](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/), but this is a bit more complex to handle.